# How to use tar with lz4?

Tags: compression, tar, lz4

How to use tar and filter the archive through [LZ4](https://github.com/lz4/lz4)? Or any available tools? It looks cumbersome to use `tar cvf folderABC.tar folderABC && lz4c -c0 folderABC.tar`.

PS: *nix environment

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[lz4](https://github.com/lz4/lz4) has a command line structure similar to [gzip](http://www.gzip.org/index.html). Therefore, something like this will work :

```
tar cvf - folderABC | lz4 > folderABC.tar.lz4
```

or

```
tar cvf - folderABC | lz4 - folderABC.tar.lz4
```

First one compresses silently, like gzip. Second one is a bit more lz4-specific, and will also display summarized compression stats.

Decompression would go like this :

```
lz4 -d folderABC.tar.lz4 -c | tar xvf -
```

Comment: Is there a standard way to add CRC32 to tar.lz4 to detect corrupted files?

Comment: lz4 already applies a 32-bits checksum by default to detect corruption. It is based on [XXH32](http://www.xxhash.com).

Comment: thanks! I used it for backing up my home dir https://gist.github.com/timabell/68d112d66623d9a4a3643c86a93debee

Comment: You might need to install ```lz4``` for ubuntu. ```sudo apt-get install liblz4-tool```

Comment: How to correctly decompress and untar `folderABC.tar.lz4`? Can pipe be uzed?

Comment: @pmor yes, pipe can be used

Answer (score 27):

On GNU `tar`, you can use `-I lz4`

Both FreeBSD and GNU tar seems to support `--use-compress-program=lz4` as well.

```
tar -I lz4 -cf archive.tar.lz4 stuff to add to archive
tar -I lz4 -xf archive.tar.lz4
```

or

```
tar --use-compress-program=lz4 -cf archive.tar.lz4 stuff to add to archive
tar --use-compress-program=lz4 -xf archive.tar.lz4
```

Comment: `You must specify one of the '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or '--test-label' options`

Comment: @Gaia I would normally use `-cf` and `-xf`. Not sure if it is portable to non GNU tar versions, so I kept the style of the question. (edited answer)

Answer (score 3):

Install lz4

```
sudo apt install lz4
```

Compress

```
tar --use-compress-program=lz4 -cvf target.lz4 /source/files
```

Decompress

```
tar --use-compress-program=lz4 -xvf target.lz4 -C /destination
```

Answer (score 2):

To use -I in GNU tar, you must specify it AFTER destination file as this:

```
tar cvf /path/to/destinationfile.tar.lz4 -I lz4 /path/to/archive
```

Comment: This is likely when using the non-dashed version of the operation options.