# Compress a folder into a single file using lz4 command line

Tags: compression, lz4

I need to compress the all of the contents of a directory into a single `lz4` archive, i couldn't figure out a way to do that. I already have read all the available parameters, still no success. Kindly suggest me how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 13):

Things like lz4, gzip, bzip2, and xz simply compress a stream of bytes. You need another utility, like tar, to convert a set of directories and files into a stream of bytes. The output of tar is then fed to the compressor. That's why you see archives with names like tar.gz or tar.xz.

[How to use tar with lz4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063846/how-to-use-tar-with-lz4)